# Are Scipy LAPACK functions parallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, lapack

I am currently using the `scipy.linalg.lapack.zheevd()` function and it runs on all cores, and produces hangs and memory overflows if I try mapping the function to an array of arguments using the `ProcessPoolExecutor()` or `ThreadPoolExecutor()` from `concurrent.futures`.

It utilizes as many cores as my test system has, but I was under the impression that things were not typically parallelized in Python due to the GIL. Is this a result of the underlying Fortran code running with OpenMP?

Is it safe to assume this is parallelized, and cannot be parallelized further? This is not a large bottleneck for my code (finding the eigensystems of 400 unique 1000x1000 matrices; although there may be need for this to be scaled up, e.g. 1000 2000x2000 matrices eventually), but I am in the optimization phase for it.

Here is a, hopefully, helpful code snippet for conceptualization, but does not represent the actual matrices:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg as la
import concurrent.futures

# In real code
#         various parameters are used to build the matrix function,
#         it is presumably not sparse

# Matrix with independent variable x
def matrix_function(x):
    # Define dimensions and pre-allocate space for matrix
    #dim = 100        # For quicker evaluation/testing
    dim = 1000        # For conveying the scale of the problem
    matrix_dimensions = [dim, dim]
    # The matrix is complex
    mat = np.zeros(matrix_dimensions, dtype=complex)
    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(i,dim):
            mat[i,j] = x*np.random.rand(1) + np.random.rand(1)*1J
            # Making the matrix Hermitian
            mat[j,i] = np.conjugate( mat[i,j] )
    return mat
        
# 400 Arguments for the defined matrix function
args = np.arange(0,10,0.025)

# Parallelizing evaluation of 400 matrices
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    evaluated_matrix_functions = pool.map( matrix_function, args )
    ''' This will hang,
             which is what tipped me off to the issue
                                          **not important to question
        eigsystem = pool.map( la.lapack.zheevd,
                              evaluated_matrix_functions
                              )
    '''
    pool.shutdown()
    
''' This will cause a memory overflow,
              depending on the size of the matrices
              and how many of them; even with 32GB memory

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    eigsystem = pool.map( la.lapack.zheevd,
                          evaluated_matrix_functions
                          )
    pool.shutdown()
'''

# The code which I run, in serial,
#          but still uses all cores/threads my 2700x provides at full load
eigensystem_list = []
for matrix in evaluated_matrix_functions:
    eigensystem_list.append( la.lapack.zheevd(matrix) )
    
# The eigensystem_list is then used in later calculations
```

Answer (score 2):

This is all controlled by the LAPACK library you are using under the hood.